# Emitting data to a separate socket.io server? socket.io-client

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I would like to emit some data, a name and an address, to another socket server, so I can insert the data into MySQL, is it possible to target a particular server, with:

```
socket.emit("foo",{var:example}
```

Thanks!

Comment: `socket.emit()` requires an already existing & open connection to a socket.io server. Then you can use `emit()`.

Comment: It also requires a close-paren.

Comment: I am aware of that yes.